# Need Javascript Code That Will Open A Webpage Then Fill Out The Form And Submit

Tags: javascript

Just as the title says, I need help with javascript code that will open a webpage and fill out the form then submit the information.

Here is what I have currently:

```
var firstName = 'Billy';
var lastName = 'Bob';
var loginWindow = window.open('my website', 'loginWindow');
loginWindow.document.getElementById('fname').value=firstName;
loginWindow.document.getElementById('lname').value=lastName;
loginWindow.document.form.submit();
```

(I found it on another post).. but it does not work for me.

Comment: You need to do more diagnosis beyond "it does not work". Poke around the JS error console.

Comment: In what way does this not work?

Comment: @MathSquared11235 FYI, you need to put http:// in the URL for markdown links to get formatted properly.

Comment: @andytuba Thanks, woops. Can't edit the comment, so will repost.

Comment: Could you either **a)** use [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to demonstrate the code, or **b)** describe exactly what happens and what you want to happen?

Comment: Nothing happens when I use this code. I want the forms to be filled then I want the form to be submitted using an external javascript or php code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be XSS (Cross-Site Scripting) restrictions on this. But, there is a solution.

Browse the source code of the form you want, find the `form` tag's `action` attribute (`<form action="THIS STUFF HERE">...</form>`), and then do one of the following in the scripting for your page:

1. Use it as the `action` of a new `form` and use the DOM to add `hidden input` elements with the `name`s and `value`s of the data you want to submit, then use `.click()` on the `submit` button to the new `form`.
2. Browse in some way to the action URL, **but** append `?name1=value1&name2=value2&name3=value3...`, where `name1` and `value1`, etc., are the names and values of the form fields you want to submit. If there is already something similar to this at the end of the `action` URL, just add on new `&name=value` pairs instead of appending a new question mark. (This could be done using an `iframe` with CSS `display: none;`.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Hey MathSquare11235, I tried these but for the action it sends it to the root of my server then into another file? Do you know the absolute path of a server because it sends it to something like this ../../filename1/filename2/file.php .

Comment: Actually, I think it is possible with Ajax. I just found out the action page but how can I send post data with ajax to a php file?

Comment: @jamming1 Just make the `action` of the new `form` or new link `../../filename1/filename2.php`.